# Wicket add other-id on label

Tags: html, attributes, label, wicket

I am new to wicket and I want to add a property (named other-id) to a label. The code is the following:

```
private String getName(ExampleList list) {
    return getBrandName() + " " + getString("ExampleList." + list.name());
}  

IModel<List<ExampleList>> listModel = new AbstractReadOnlyModel<List<ExampleList>>() {
            @Override
            public List<ExampleList> getObject() {
                return availableTechnologies.getObject().keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
            }
        };


ListView<ExampleList> example = new ListView<ExampleList>("list", listModel) {
            @Override
            protected void populateItem(ListItem<ExampleList> el) {
                el.add(new Radio<ExampleList>("radio", item.getModel()));
                el.add(new Label("labelName", getName(el.getModelObject())));               
            }
        };
```

And this is the corresponding html:

```
<li wicket:id="list" class="radio">
      <input wicket:id="radio" type="radio" name="radioChoice"/>
      <label wicket:for="radio"><wicket:container wicket:id="labelName" /></label>
</li>
```

I want to add other-id to the label with label name into the other-id. Until now I tried

```
el.add(new Label("labelName", getName(el.getModelObject())).add(new AttributeAppender("other-id", getName(el.getModel())));
```

but nothing appeared in my label.
I also tried in html:

```
<label wicket:for="radio" other-id= wicket:id="labelName">
```

but it's giving me error at my last try.
Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To set a label on a form component, you need to use the `setLabel` method. In your `populateItem` method, you can do the following:

```
Radio<ExampleList> radio = new Radio<>("radio", item.getModel())
radio.setLabel(Model.of(getName(el.getModelObject())));

el.add(radio);
```

To make this work, you should modify your HTML to remove the `wicket:container` inside the label:

```
<li wicket:id="list" class="radio">
  <input wicket:id="radio" type="radio" name="radioChoice"/>
  <label wicket:for="radio"></label>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you add the AttributeAppender to `wicket:container`. This element renders only its body, i.e. the label's text, but the tag itself is not rendered and because of this its attributes are also not rendered.

You can change your markup to:

```
<label wicket:for="radio" wicket:id="labelName"></label>
```

This way the AttributeAppender will add the new attribute to the `<label>` element.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change the html. I tried it, but it gave me another error, so I should keep that format with wicket:container

Comment: Internet-failure message appears instead of the page with the specific list

Comment: Please create a mini application that demonstrates the issue and share it at GitHub/GitLab/BitBucket/... and we will take a look!